# Need help to understand how the app packed by py2app works

Tags: python, py2app

I'm using `py2app` to package my Python code(`Tkinter` app), but I'm facing a very strange problem.

I have two Macs, they both have an intel CPU, and they both have the same python version 3.9.8 installed. I packed my App on Mac1 using `py2app`, it works totally fine. However, on my another Mac2, if I run `./dist/MyApplication.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApplication`  in the terminal, it works totally fine as well, but if I run `./dist/MyApplication.app` directly, it still works, I mean I can still open my App, but some functions will report an error. In addition, if I run the python code on Mac2, it also works totally fine.

I'm sorry I can't provide a reproducible example, but can someone give me a hint or any idea what is going on? How I can debug this issue? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possibly applications works with different environment set - especially sys.path. You can try printing it somewhere after appication startup. Maybe some libraries are used not from your packaged application, but from another paths, available through your environment, and due to differencies between systems it work in one but not in another?

Comment: @MaciejWrobel, thanks for your help, I partially solved this problem, I found that if I put the APP in the `/downloads` folder it has problems, but if I put it in the `/Downloads/chile_folder` file it works fine, also if I put it in the `Applications` folder it works fine.